# MySQL - removal of duplicate results in JSON_ARRAYAGG in the presence of GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, database

I have query:

```
SELECT id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(url) AS urlLinks
FROM links
WHERE id=832781
GROUP BY id;
```

The result of this query duplicates the same image urls in column `urlLinks`:

```
["index.html", "index.html", "index.html", "index.html", "index.html"]
```

How can I leave as a result only unique image urls?

```
["index.html"]
```

`GROUP BY` cannot be removed from the request!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON_ARRAYAGG()` does not support `DISTINCT`. You can `SELECT DISTINCT` in a subquery, and then aggregate:

```
SELECT id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(url) AS urlLinks
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id, url from links) l
WHERE id=832781
GROUP BY id;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e80703be28b112a01505edec218d68b)**:

```
WITH links AS (
    SELECT 832781 id, 'index.html' url
    UNION ALL SELECT 832781, 'index.html'
    UNION ALL SELECT 832781, 'page.html'
)
SELECT id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(url) AS urlLinks
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id, url from links) l
WHERE id=832781
GROUP BY id;
```

```
    id | urlLinks                   
-----: | :--------------------------
832781 | ["index.html", "page.html"]
```